# While loop with node and parentNode not reaching end

Tags: javascript, nodes, parent-node

I'm trying to do a simple loop and check if nodes/`parentNode` class name matches a string in a array. Code is as follows:

```
function isInside(list,node) {
    while( node !== undefined ) {
        for( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ )
            if( node.className.indexOf(list[i]) > -1 )
                return true;
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    alert(1); // The code does not reach this when false
    return false;
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: Change `node !== undefined` to `node !== null` since `null` will be the result of there being no `.parentNode`. You could also use `!= null`, which will test for both `undefined` and `null`, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Changing 'node !== undefined' to 'node != null' did not work.. Any other ideas?

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/qxAt4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this pattern:

```
var current = node;
while (current.parentNode){
 // do stuff with node
 current = current.parentNode

}
```